# BIND9 DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to set up my own DNS server on solaris 10. I used the setup guide from http://www.logiqwest.com/dataCenter/Demos/RunBooks/DNS/DNSsetup.html and
I tried to join Windows XP clients to the domain I had configured using the above guide, but I was unable to join. I received the following errors:

> An error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used
>   to locate adomain controller for domain MYDOMAIN.COM.
>
> The error was: "No records found for given DNS query."
>
> (error code 0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)

The query was for the `SRV` record for `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.MYDOMAIN.COM`

Where could I be going wrong? Your assistance will highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but the answer is simple: you need to register a SRV record in the zone (mydomain.com) for the dc's entries. It will tell the clients where to find the DC.

Something along the lines of

```
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs IN SRV 0 100 389 hostname-of-dc.mydomain.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else attempting to do this, here is what a valid query response looks like.  This assuming you have the following topology:

Domain = my.domain
AD1 = server1 (192.168.0.1)
AD2 = server2 (192.168.0.2)
BIND DNS = 192.168.0.5

```
$ dig _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain SRV @192.168.0.5                                                                

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain SRV @192.168.0.5
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38775
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain. IN SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain. 600 IN  SRV 0 100 389 server1.my.domain.
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain. 600 IN  SRV 0 100 389 server2.my.domain.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
_msdcs.my.domain.   2649    IN  NS  server1.my.domain.
_msdcs.my.domain.   2649    IN  NS  server2.my.domain.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
server1.my.domain.  3600    IN  A   192.168.0.1
server2.my.domain.  3600    IN  A   192.168.0.2

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.5#53(192.168.0.5)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep 20 13:01:36 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 191
```